# Conditional PR build based on pom version

Tags: maven, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

we currently have a Jenkins PR build run for every PR we makes. As a part of this process we also wanted to check few condition , whether the PR contains pom.xml changes? if it contains pom.xml changes check the version of library jars inside the pom.xml with pom.xml which is downloaded from the nexus.

basically the idea is to avoid changing any of the library version of pom.xml with the any of the PR, build should not happen if the version of the library changes.

```
 <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
```

check this version and and see if it changed from the previous version in nexus and if its not changed continue the build else fail the build.

Is there any plugin or conditional PR build option, please suggest.

Comment: Have you looked at the maven-enforcer-plugin? If you don't want to allow changes to dependency versions, perhaps you should have a BOM pom in another project

Comment: Hint: You can [replace `<maven.compiler.source|target>` with `<maven.compiler.release>` since Java 9](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version#java9).